# Separating Class Functions From Rest of Class Definition

Tags: c++

I have a school assignment involving a multi-threaded problem. I'm not here to ask for help with the implementation of the specific problem, especially because I haven't even gotten there yet. For this assignment, I must define a few classes that descend from a provided Thread class. For this definition, I have a main file (thread.cpp), a header file (thread.h), and a support file containing functions to be called by the classes defined in thread.cpp (thread-support.cpp).

thread.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef _THREAD_H
#define _THREAD_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "ThreadClass.h"

Mutex potLock;
Mutex mamaLock;
Semaphore sleepyMama("SleepyMama", 0);
bool awake = false;

class Mama : public Thread {
    public:
        Mama();

    private:
        void ThreadFunc();
        void goto_sleep();
        void food_ready();
};

class Baby : public Thread {
    public:
        Baby(int id, Mutex* pots);

    private:
        void ThreadFunc();
        int id;
        Mama mama;
        Mutex *pots;
        void ready_to_eat();
        void finish_eating();
};

#endif
```

thread.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "thread.h"
using namespace std;

Baby::Baby(int ID, Mutex feedPots[]) :
          id(ID), pots(feedPots)
{
    ThreadName.seekp(0, ios::beg);
    ThreadName << "Baby" << id << '\0';
}

void Baby::ThreadFunc() {
    Thread::ThreadFunc();
    mamaLock.Lock();
    if (!awake) {
        sleepyMama.Signal();
    }
    mamaLock.Unlock();
    Exit();
}

Mama::Mama()
{
    ThreadName.seekp(0, ios::beg);
    ThreadName << "Mama" << '\0';
}

void Mama::ThreadFunc() {
    char buf[200];
    Thread::ThreadFunc();
    sprintf(buf, "Mama started\n");
    write(1, buf, strlen(buf));

    goto_sleep();

    sprintf(buf, "Mama woke up!\n");
    write(1, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

And thread-support.cpp currently looks like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "thread.h"

void Mama::goto_sleep() {
    mamaLock.Lock();
    awake = false;
    mamaLock.Unlock();
    sleepyMama.Wait();
}
```

Currently, I'm using a Makefile that compiles each of the .cpp files into .o files using g++ with the flags -g and -02 (because that's what our example file had) along with other flags to make it work with our ancient custom threading library. The executable compiles with the command `c++ [custom library flags] -g -02 -o prog4 thread.o thread-support.o thread-main.o` with thread-main.cpp being the file with the main function in it, which includes thread.h. The Mutexes, Semaphore, and bool in thread.h need to be accessible to both thread.cpp and thread-support.cpp, but if I include thread.h in both files, I get multiple definition issues. I get multiple definition issues in thread-main as well.

Comment: Why do you have thread-support.cpp? You aren't separating out by class so why not use a single cpp file? BTW the reason for your difficulties in duplicate definitions is because of the top level variables in `thread.h`.

Comment: So stop defining things in headers.

Comment: Either make them static in the class or at least put them in a namespace.

Comment: I have thread-support.cpp because I literally have to have it. It's in the spec for the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.cpp` should define these variables:

```
Mutex potLock;
Mutex mamaLock;
Semaphore sleepyMama("SleepyMama", 0);
bool awake = false;
```

While `Thread.h` should only declare them:

```
extern Mutex potLock;
extern Mutex mamaLock;
extern Semaphore sleepyMama;
extern bool awake;
```

You should always (well, in most cases) define variables in `.cpp` files. Headers should only contain forward declarations to make certain symbols visible to other modules.

**EDIT**

To have these simbols available in `thread-support.cpp`, you can either:

**1)** `#include Thread.h`

**2)** Declare them manually - in `thread-support.cpp` add:

```
extern Mutex potLock;
extern Mutex mamaLock;
extern Semaphore sleepyMama;
extern bool awake;
```

Comment: Would these variables be accessible in `thread-support.cpp` ? I'd rather have everything within `thread.cpp`, but I technically am not allowed to.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to work. If I wasn't following an assignment spec, I would put everything a class needs in one file.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you are not using header guards.

In your header files or wherever you include thread.h

Wrap it with this

## ifndef INC_THREAD_H

## define INC_THREAD-H

//all of your code herein

## endif

Replace all of your code here, with your complete header file, then also use it in thread support around the include statement